# Determine the currently installed version of a Composer package from within that package

Tags: php, git, composer-php

Say, I have a package which someone installed. Now, I want to make a debugging report which will show exactly which versions is currently installed.

I could have looked into `.git` and fetch the last tag:

```
git describe --tags --dirty=-dev --always
```

But this won't work as Composer by default installs packages from archives which include no `.git` ([`--prefer-dist` is set by default](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i)). And one cannot reliably force users install with `--prefer-source`, and it is not like this would make much sense.

How do I get the package version currently installed? Can I get it without exploring output of `composer show ...` or even running any external commands at all?

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this problem is to [use `export-subst` for a file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_code_export_subst_code), say `src/Version.php`, then adding the following constant:

```php
const VERSION_INFO = '$Format:%h%d$';
```

And tell Git to replace the placeholders in this file:

```sh
$ grep export-subst .gitattributes
/src/Version.php        export-subst
```

Then, on export, this constant will be replaced like in the following example:

```sh
$ git tag -m "Releasing v1.0.1" -a v1.0.1
$ git archive v1.0.1 | grep -a VERSION_INFO
    const VERSION_INFO = '12abc34 (HEAD -> master, tag: v1.0.1)';
```

Next you can check if `self::VERSION_INFO` begins with a dollar sign, and if not-parse out the version and the commit ID with a simple regular expression like:

```php
class Version
{
    const VERSION_INFO = '12abc34 (HEAD -> master, tag: v1.0.1)';

    static function getVersion(): string
    {
        if (self::VERSION_INFO[0] === '$') {
            // get a version from Git (--git-dir may be of use here)
            return exec('git describe --tags --dirty=-dev --always');
        }

        if (preg_match('/^([0-9a-f]+).*?tag: (v?[\d\.]+)/', self::VERSION_INFO, $matched)) {
            return "{$matched[2]}-{$matched[1]}";
        }

        // cannot parse: return version string as is (fallback to other methods?)
        return self::VERSION_INFO;
    }
}
```

Note that this version string may not include a branch name though:

```sh
git log --pretty=format:%h%d
```

(Yet another option is to [use Ocramius' PackageVersions](https://github.com/Ocramius/PackageVersions), but this package may not be installed.)